# why I got reference error and What is wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript

```js
let radius = [3, 2, 1, 4];

function area(radius) {
    let tArea = [];
    let circumference = [];
    let diameter = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < radius.length; i++) {
        tArea.push(Math.PI * radius[i] * radius[i]);
        circumference.push(2 * Math.PI * radius[i]);
        diameter.push(2 * radius[i]);
    }
    return tArea;
    return circumference;
    return diameter;
}

console.log(area(radius));
console.log(area(circumference));
console.log(area(diameter));
```

hello experts, I'm not getting, why this code does not work.
I'm getting a reference error. please explain if possible and teach me how to debug the code so I wont be disturbing you guys for small errors.
Thank you.

Comment: I'm at a loss to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: you call `area(circumference)`, `circumference` not exist in the current main scope but in  `area` function.

Comment: The first `return` is where it ends processing the function, so the `return circumference` does not happen. Perhaps you could make each return into a separate function. Also, why would anyone expect a function named "area" to also return a circumference and diameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you are trying to do, but here are few things you are doing wrong.

1. **`circumeference` and `diameter` are defined inside the function scope** and you are trying to access it outside the function, which is causing this error.
2. **You are trying to return multiple values from a function using multiple return statements** which is not possible since the first return will end the function. For your purpose you can simply return an object from the function, containing your desired values.

See the code below,

```js
let radius = [3, 2, 1, 4];

function area(radius) {
    let tArea = [];
    let circumference = [];
    let diameter = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < radius.length; i++) {
        tArea.push(Math.PI * radius[i] * radius[i]);
        circumference.push(2 * Math.PI * radius[i]);
        diameter.push(2 * radius[i]);
    }
    return {area: tArea, circumference, diameter};
}

const {area: calculatedArea, circumference, diameter} = area(radius);

console.log(calculatedArea);
console.log(circumference);
console.log(diameter);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that was my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Because you can return only a single value from a function while you are trying to return 3 . Declare these 3 arrays globally and you won't need the return statements.